# Star rating System, Give unique rating

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rating

I am using Star system to rate some films from database, i am adding those films in a while loop, and stars along with each film.

I want the user to give the unique rating to each film, like if the user has given five stars to one film then if he try to give the five five stars again to some other film , there must be some indication to show
 turn the stars from yellow to red, before submitting the the rating. Can someone give me some samples.

```css
.star-rating {
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  /* width: 250px; remove this */
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAgMjAiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDIwIDIwIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48cG9seWdvbiBmaWxsPSIjREREREREIiBwb2ludHM9IjEwLDAgMTMuMDksNi41ODMgMjAsNy42MzkgMTUsMTIuNzY0IDE2LjE4LDIwIDEwLDE2LjU4MyAzLjgyLDIwIDUsMTIuNzY0IDAsNy42MzkgNi45MSw2LjU4MyAiLz48L3N2Zz4=');
  background-size: contain;
}
.star-rating i {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  /* width: 20%; remove this */
  z-index: 1;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAgMjAiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDIwIDIwIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48cG9seWdvbiBmaWxsPSIjRkZERjg4IiBwb2ludHM9IjEwLDAgMTMuMDksNi41ODMgMjAsNy42MzkgMTUsMTIuNzY0IDE2LjE4LDIwIDEwLDE2LjU4MyAzLjgyLDIwIDUsMTIuNzY0IDAsNy42MzkgNi45MSw2LjU4MyAiLz48L3N2Zz4=');
  background-size: contain;
}
.star-rating input {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  /* width: 20%; remove this */
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
.star-rating input:hover + i,
.star-rating input:checked + i {
  opacity: 1;
}
.star-rating i ~ i {
  width: 40%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i {
  width: 60%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i ~ i {
  width: 80%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i {
  width: 100%;
}
 ::after,
 ::before {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.star-rating.star-5 {
  width: 250px;
}
.star-rating.star-5 input,
.star-rating.star-5 i {
  width: 20%;
}
.star-rating.star-5 i ~ i {
  width: 40%;
}
.star-rating.star-5 i ~ i ~ i {
  width: 60%;
}
.star-rating.star-5 i ~ i ~ i ~ i {
  width: 80%;
}
.star-rating.star-5 i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~i {
  width: 100%;
}
.star-rating.star-3 {
  width: 150px;
}
.star-rating.star-3 input,
.star-rating.star-3 i {
  width: 33.33%;
}
.star-rating.star-3 i ~ i {
  width: 66.66%;
}
.star-rating.star-3 i ~ i ~ i {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form method="get" action="" id="form1">
  <span class="star-rating star-5">
          <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1"><i></i>
          <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2"><i></i>
          <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3"><i></i>
          <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4"><i></i>
          <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5"><i></i>
        </span>
</form>
```

Further i will store the rating using PHP, once this problem resolves.
Below is the code that i am using.

Thanks for any Help :-)``

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a class `already-given` to already given ratings so that if this class is prensent with previous `star-rating` class it will use orange star

```
.star-rating.already input:hover+ i
{
  background: url('/*Url of orange star*/');!important
}

<form method="get" action="" id="form1">
  <span class="star-rating star-5 already-given">
          <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1"><i></i>
          <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2"><i></i>
          <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3"><i></i>
          <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" checked><i></i>
          <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5"><i></i>
        </span>
</form>
```

**Jquery code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type=radio]").on("change",function(){
    $(this).parents(".star-rating").removeClass("already-given").addClass("already-given");
  });
});
```

EDIT:

[Jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb9ypptb/) (*please remove red color with url of orange star*)

[Check this also](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb9ypptb/3/) (changes made as asked in comment)

Comment: Please help me with jquery

Comment: @LizaAsh there is no jquery used here. can you be more specific

Comment: Need Jquery to add this CSS when clicked.

Comment: but in this we can give similar rating to both

Comment: Check this Demo @LizaAsh https://jsfiddle.net/Lb9ypptb/3/ . is this what you want?

Comment: this is good but when i change the rating it remains to red(already class)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://codepen.io/pk-op-06/pen/QWMNPJg) simplest way to create Star Rating using
`HTML`, `CSS` and `Javascript`.
Here you can create a new element, after rating div to display or store the index as a rating for the movie you want.